# Arabic Data Transfer From Excel (.xls) to AS/400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I need to transfer excel data (.xls) having Arabic data columns to AS/400. Is their any possibility or way to transfer the same to AS/400. please help steps to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the older IBM Client Access product, there's a plug-in included for Excel that lets you transfer data to/from the IBM i directly from Excel.

If you have newer replacement IBM Access Client Solution (ACS), the same functionality is there but built into the Data Transfer component of ACS instead of an Excel plugin.

In either case, you'll need to make sure that the table you are transfer data into is tagged with an appropriate CCSID.

Assuming a new table, consider using UNICODE for the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the .xls as a csv. 
Transfer the file to a directory in the IFS on the AS400 (Now IBM i on Power). Make sure the CCSID of the file in the IFS is 1208.

You can then use the CPYFRMIMPF command to copy the data to your AS400 file. The AS400 file must also have a CCSID capable of storing UNICODE data. possible CCSID's are 13488, 1200 or 1208.

Comment: CPYFRMIMPF works fine, and you can make your life easier if you create an IFS share and have the PC user save the spreadsheet directly to the IFS.  Then a CLP can run that doesn't require any end user action - they already did their part when they saved the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answers already given, you can use Python (part of 5733OPS) to read a spreadsheet directly.  Also, XLPARSE2 at www.easy400.net has a utility called XLSTABLE which will create a DB2 table directly from a spreadsheet.   Also, Scott Klement's HSSFCGI will let an RPG program read a spreadsheet directly.  Both of these last 2 use Java HSSF / POI, so if you haven't used Java on IBM i before, that may be more work than you are looking to do.